# Time Series in Stata: var vs. regress

Tags: time-series, stata, var

I am seeking your insight on the differences between the var and regress commands in Stata. Given the same variables and the same number of lags, what makes these models different (judging by the differences in their outputs)?

```
var y x1 x2, lags(1/7)

regress L(1/7).y L(1/7).x1 L(1/7).x2
```

The series were transformed into stationary beforehand.

```
var y x1 x2, lags(1/7)

 Vector autoregression

 Sample:  9 - 159                                   No. of obs      =       151
 Log likelihood = -2461.622                         AIC             =  33.47844
 FPE            =  7.00e+10                         HQIC            =  34.01421
 Det(Sigma_ml)  =  2.90e+10                         SBIC            =  34.79725

 Equation           Parms      RMSE     R-sq      chi2     P>chi2
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
         y           22     627.086   0.4632   130.3037   0.0000
         x1           22     16.4642   0.4150   107.1156   0.0000
         x2           22     34.8932   0.3821   93.37647   0.0000
 ----------------------------------------------------------------

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
 ----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
            y    |
               y |
             L1. |  -.8034219   .0870606    -9.23   0.000    -.9740576   -.6327862
             L2. |   -.829339   .1112633    -7.45   0.000    -1.047411    -.611267
             L3. |  -.6881525   .1268751    -5.42   0.000    -.9368231   -.4394818
             L4. |  -.5958702   .1316349    -4.53   0.000    -.8538699   -.3378706
             L5. |  -.4941909   .1285658    -3.84   0.000    -.7461752   -.2422066
             L6. |  -.3478784   .1130961    -3.08   0.002    -.5695426   -.1262142
             L7. |  -.1273106   .0892459    -1.43   0.154    -.3022294    .0476083
                 |
              x1 |
             L1. |   2.814694   4.697886     0.60   0.549    -6.392995    12.02238
             L2. |   13.40258   5.712821     2.35   0.019     2.205654     24.5995
             L3. |   13.41822   6.119334     2.19   0.028     1.424542    25.41189
             L4. |   7.634082   6.373183     1.20   0.231    -4.857128    20.12529
             L5. |   2.001271   5.898859     0.34   0.734     -9.56028    13.56282
             L6. |   3.421364   5.569404     0.61   0.539    -7.494468     14.3372
             L7. |   4.068799    4.46953     0.91   0.363    -4.691319    12.82892
                 |
              x2 |
             L1. |  -.5105249   2.210646    -0.23   0.817    -4.843312    3.822262
             L2. |  -2.108354   2.495037    -0.85   0.398    -6.998537     2.78183
             L3. |  -1.442043   2.592775    -0.56   0.578    -6.523789    3.639704
             L4. |  -.9065004   2.620667    -0.35   0.729    -6.042914    4.229913
             L5. |  -.0001391    2.53355    -0.00   1.000    -4.965806    4.965528
             L6. |   2.146481   2.427015     0.88   0.376    -2.610381    6.903343
             L7. |  -1.118613   2.118762    -0.53   0.598    -5.271309    3.034084
                 |
           _cons |   22.43668   48.04635     0.47   0.641    -71.73243    116.6058
 ----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         x1      |
               y |
             L1. |   .0036968   .0022858     1.62   0.106    -.0007833    .0081768
             L2. |   .0012158   .0029212     0.42   0.677    -.0045097    .0069413
             L3. |   .0035081   .0033311     1.05   0.292    -.0030208     .010037
             L4. |   .0032596   .0034561     0.94   0.346    -.0035142    .0100334
             L5. |   .0005852   .0033755     0.17   0.862    -.0060307     .007201
             L6. |  -.0018743   .0029693    -0.63   0.528    -.0076941    .0039455
             L7. |  -.0040389   .0023432    -1.72   0.085    -.0086314    .0005537
                 |
              x1 |
             L1. |  -.5753736   .1233434    -4.66   0.000    -.8171223   -.3336249
             L2. |  -.3020477   .1499906    -2.01   0.044    -.5960239   -.0080714
             L3. |  -.3313213   .1606637    -2.06   0.039    -.6462164   -.0164263
             L4. |  -.1718872   .1673285    -1.03   0.304    -.4998451    .1560707
             L5. |  -.1834757   .1548751    -1.18   0.236    -.4870253    .1200739
             L6. |   .0489376   .1462252     0.33   0.738    -.2376586    .3355337
             L7. |   .1766427   .1173479     1.51   0.132     -.053355    .4066404
                 |
              x2 |
             L1. |  -.1051509   .0580407    -1.81   0.070    -.2189086    .0086069
             L2. |  -.1006968   .0655074    -1.54   0.124     -.229089    .0276954
             L3. |  -.0906552   .0680736    -1.33   0.183    -.2240769    .0427665
             L4. |  -.1436015   .0688059    -2.09   0.037    -.2784585   -.0087445
             L5. |  -.0930764   .0665186    -1.40   0.162    -.2234505    .0372976
             L6. |  -.1018913   .0637215    -1.60   0.110    -.2267832    .0230006
             L7. |  -.1194924   .0556283    -2.15   0.032    -.2285218   -.0104629
                 |
           _cons |   1.918878   1.261461     1.52   0.128     -.553541    4.391296
 ----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
              x2 |
               y |
             L1. |   .0010281   .0048444     0.21   0.832    -.0084667    .0105228
             L2. |  -.0038838   .0061911    -0.63   0.530    -.0160181    .0082505
             L3. |   .0035605   .0070598     0.50   0.614    -.0102764    .0173974
             L4. |   .0041767   .0073246     0.57   0.569    -.0101793    .0185327
             L5. |   .0007593   .0071538     0.11   0.915     -.013262    .0147806
             L6. |  -.0027897   .0062931    -0.44   0.658    -.0151239    .0095445
             L7. |   .0018272    .004966     0.37   0.713    -.0079059    .0115603
                 |
              x1 |
             L1. |   .3332696   .2614066     1.27   0.202     -.179078    .8456172
             L2. |   .6160613   .3178811     1.94   0.053    -.0069742    1.239097
             L3. |   .4139762   .3405009     1.22   0.224    -.2533934    1.081346
             L4. |   .2837896   .3546259     0.80   0.424    -.4112645    .9788436
             L5. |   .4448436   .3282329     1.36   0.175    -.1984811    1.088168
             L6. |   .6417029   .3099009     2.07   0.038     .0343084    1.249098
             L7. |   .4719593   .2487001     1.90   0.058    -.0154839    .9594025
                 |
              x2 |
             L1. |  -.7465681    .123008    -6.07   0.000    -.9876594   -.5054769
             L2. |  -.6760273   .1388325    -4.87   0.000     -.948134   -.4039206
             L3. |  -.4367948    .144271    -3.03   0.002    -.7195607   -.1540289
             L4. |  -.4889316    .145823    -3.35   0.001    -.7747393   -.2031238
             L5. |  -.5310379   .1409755    -3.77   0.000    -.8073447    -.254731
             L6. |  -.4416263   .1350475    -3.27   0.001    -.7063146   -.1769381
             L7. |  -.3265204   .1178952    -2.77   0.006    -.5575907     -.09545
                 |
           _cons |   3.568261   2.673465     1.33   0.182    -1.671634    8.808155
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------



regress L(1/7).y L(1/7).x1 L(1/7).x2

          Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =     151
    -------------+------------------------------           F( 20,   130) =    7.23
           Model |  49291082.3    20  2464554.11           Prob > F      =  0.0000
        Residual |  44322342.8   130  340941.099           R-squared     =  0.5265
    -------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.4537
           Total |  93613425.1   150  624089.501           Root MSE      =   583.9

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            L.y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
    ----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
               y |
             L2. |  -.8074369   .0868829    -9.29   0.000    -.9793244   -.6355494
             L3. |  -.7857941   .1076428    -7.30   0.000    -.9987525   -.5728357
             L4. |  -.6747462   .1186733    -5.69   0.000    -.9095271   -.4399654
             L5. |  -.5758927   .1192639    -4.83   0.000     -.811842   -.3399433
             L6. |  -.4199846   .1078154    -3.90   0.000    -.6332845   -.2066846
             L7. |  -.2444889   .0873128    -2.80   0.006    -.4172267    -.071751
                 |
              x1 |
             L1. |   9.174249   4.663798     1.97   0.051    -.0525176    18.40102
             L2. |   6.026435   5.730833     1.05   0.295    -5.311334     17.3642
             L3. |   13.03098   6.057813     2.15   0.033     1.046324    25.01564
             L4. |   13.01178   6.318175     2.06   0.041     .5120225    25.51153
             L5. |   6.146548    5.91807     1.04   0.301    -5.561646    17.85474
             L6. |   .8687361   5.610159     0.15   0.877    -10.23029    11.96776
             L7. |  -.6015264   4.502342    -0.13   0.894    -9.508873     8.30582
                 |
              x2 |
             L1. |   2.709283   2.214315     1.22   0.223    -1.671474    7.090041
             L2. |   2.947753   2.500195     1.18   0.241    -1.998585     7.89409
             L3. |   .7449778   2.611172     0.29   0.776    -4.420914    5.910869
             L4. |   .8159876   2.639117     0.31   0.758    -4.405191    6.037166
             L5. |   1.839693    2.54722     0.72   0.471    -3.199677    6.879062
             L6. |   2.267241   2.436901     0.93   0.354    -2.553876    7.088358
             L7. |   4.198018   2.102467     2.00   0.048     .0385389    8.357497
                 |
           _cons |  -3.078699   48.40164    -0.06   0.949    -98.83556    92.67816
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

For me they have two different specifications .

The first one (VAR) is estimating the impact of the lags of three independent variables to the dependent variable (y, x1, x2) one at time. The second one is estimating the impact of Lags from 2:7 of y + Lags from (1:7) of x1 + Lags from (1:7) of x2 on the dependent variable L(y). So they have two different dependent variables and independent variables on the y side. See equations below (The first three are for `var` code and the last one is for `regress` code):

[image]

The OLS specification does not take into account the feedback effect that exists between the variables in your model. Although you maybe interested in the effect of say X1 on y, but X1 is also affect by y and its lag values- the feedback effect. for this reason, using OLS will result in spurious regression.